# Как сделать пагинацию изображений выводимых через путь MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть страница на которой выводится сетка из изображений, которые хранятся в папке, а выводятся на страницу благодаря запросу `MySQL`, где хранятся пути к изображениям.

Нужно сделать пагинацию с этими изображениями. Чтобы, скажем, на первой странице выводилось 40 изображений и на последующих страницах так же. Как это можно сделать?

```
<?php
$img_url = "uploads/";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT images.id as imgid, images.image_name, images.user_id_fk, users.id, users.login FROM images,users WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id ORDER BY images.created ".$sort);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '
<div class="column is-one-quarter container1">
    <a href="img.php?img='.$row['imgid'].'">
        <figure class="image image is-square">
            <img style="object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer;" src="'.$img_url.$row['image_name'].'" />
        </figure>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">'.$row['login'].'</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
';
}
?>
```

Comment: так же как и любую другую пагинацию с помощью инструкции `LIMIT` в запросе

Comment: какую технологию пагинации вы используете?

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут почитайте про LIMIT:
https://ruhighload.com/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+mysql+limit

Дальше используйте удобный для вас paginator. Либо пишите свой.